# Efficiency of multiple requests vs one large request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, react-native

I am working on an analytics dashboard where the user can select between different chart timelines; a week, month, and year.

The data on the server is somewhat complicated and nested, (using mongoDB) but in this form.

```
[
    {date: "2019-12-08T13:55:24.726-06:00", otherData: ...},
    {date: "2019-12-09T13:55:24.726-06:00", otherData: ...},
    {date: "2019-12-10T13:55:24.726-06:00", otherData: ...},
]
```

Each object has a date for a specific day and there will typically only be one object per day, and then a bunch of other data in each object that I need to map through to get the data points I need for the charts.

I am curious if it is more efficient to make a separate HTTP request for each time length, so for example if the user clicks on the "month" button my app requests the last months worth of data, because then I can do all of the calculations on the server side, such as grouping by dates, mapping through data, diffing dates to get durations, etc.

Or if it would be more efficient to make one HTTP request on app init, for the max amount of time (one year) and then filter, parse, and map the data client side to display to the user depending what time length they choose.

My app is a react native app, so because of that the users hardware capability might be a factor, but network connectivity could also be a factor.

What do you think is a better design decision?

Comment: I have always found that it is more efficient and easier to scale if you can push the work down to the database. What happens if for one year you have an influx of data? Your front-end of your application won't scale and you could give the idea to the user that your app is just "slow". Where if you let the database do the work, you will get more consistent performance even for larger workloads. Even if your database can't do all the manipulation needed, your back-end is easier for you to scale also.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for replying!  I guess my concern at this point is that there will be a lot of network requests because the user will probably be toggling between these different time lengths frequently, but I guess like you say, if the data gets large the delay might end up being more to parse it than the delay of the network call....

Comment: If data doesn't change after a certain amount of time, you could also store it in the browser's localstorage. Then you could just check if it exists there before making another network call.

Comment: Whilst this might not be applicable to your use case, it's worth mentioning anyway.  I wrote a search page where the returned results could be in the hundreds of thousands.  I had a similar quandary.  Make the user wait, could take a couple of minutes.  Introduce pagination, that seemed complex.  Instead, I used pipes and streams.  With streams, the back-end does a 'chunk' of processing, sends those results to the client and moves onto the next chunk.

Comment: ...  This worked really well for me as each time the client received a chunk of data, I could update a display message, e.g. "Received x rows of data".  With pipes and streams, you can also make transformations on the data between retrieving it from the db and sending to the client.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for that idea @ChrisAdams I like it!  I will look into streams a bit more